# MYSQL and PHP: SELECT subquery without result returns array key with empty value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with games, articles (reviews + previews) and videos (video reviews + video previews). I have a game with id `233` and I want to find one review, one preview, one video review and video preview, if these are present.

To do this, I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT (SELECT article_url
        FROM   articles
        WHERE  articles_game_id = 233
               AND artikel_sort = 'review'
               AND article_online = 1
        ORDER  BY article_datetime DESC
        LIMIT  1) AS review,

       (SELECT article_url
        FROM   articles
        WHERE  articles_game_id = 233
               AND artikel_sort = 'preview'
               AND article_online = 1
        ORDER  BY article_datetime DESC
        LIMIT  1) AS preview,

       (SELECT trailer_url
        FROM   trailers
        WHERE  trailer_game_id = 233
               AND trailer_sort = 'video review'
               AND trailer_online = 1
        ORDER  BY trailer_datetime DESC
        LIMIT  1) AS videoreview,

       (SELECT trailer_url
        FROM   trailers
        WHERE  trailer_game_id = 233
               AND trailer_sort = 'video preview'
               AND trailer_online = 1
        ORDER  BY trailer_datetime DESC
        LIMIT  1) AS videopreview
FROM   articles
```

However, this query has two problems:

- It queries the database five times, which does not seem very efficient to me.
- If there is no review (for example), the resulting PHP array does have a key/value pair with the key 'review', but its value is empty. However, I would like this key/value pair to be totally absent, so I can simply loop over the array and print each key/value pair as a link.

Does anybody know an efficient way to solve this problem? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: left join will not result correct records because of `ORDER BY trailer_datetime DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: Are you sure that you have an efficiency problem here? Databases are very good at doing queries, and will generally optimise stuff like this behind the scenes, if it's called a lot (and if it's not called a lot, does it matter how quick it is?). Do you have evidence that your application is actually spending a lot of time on this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this seems to be a task, where you cannot get away using separate queries. However, I would use `union` to combine the results of the queries, rather than joins, or subqueries in the select list, or separate queries.

1. With union there is only 1 roundtrip between the client and the database
2. If a query in the union does not return any rows, then it will not be in the resultset (see requirements in OP). Pls note, that the `type` field's value will tell you the type of the url returned.

Sample code:

```
SELECT article_url, 'review' as type
        FROM   articles
        WHERE  articles_game_id = 233
               AND artikel_sort = 'review'
               AND article_online = 1
        ORDER  BY article_datetime DESC
        LIMIT  1
UNION ALL
SELECT article_url, 'preview'
        FROM   articles
        WHERE  articles_game_id = 233
               AND artikel_sort = 'preview'
               AND article_online = 1
        ORDER  BY article_datetime DESC
        LIMIT  1
UNION ALL
SELECT trailer_url, 'video review'
        FROM   trailers
        WHERE  trailer_game_id = 233
               AND trailer_sort = 'video review'
               AND trailer_online = 1
        ORDER  BY trailer_datetime DESC
        LIMIT  1
UNION ALL
SELECT trailer_url, 'video preview'
        FROM   trailers
        WHERE  trailer_game_id = 233
               AND trailer_sort = 'video preview'
               AND trailer_online = 1
        ORDER  BY trailer_datetime DESC
        LIMIT  1
```

An alternative solution could be to use a subquery to get the max date (or id, if the article / trailer ids are auto_increment fields). However, you would need 2 subqueries (1 or article, 1 trailers), then 2 queries in which the subqueries are joined back to article / trailer tables, and a 5th one top combine them into 1 query, so I will not describe this approach.

Comment: The only downside here is that instead of performing a PDO `fetch` (which would result in a single array looking like `Array('review' => 'review_url', 'preview' => 'preview_url')`, I have to perform a `fetchAll`, which results in a nested array looking like `Array([0] => Array([url] => 'review_url', [type] => 'review'), [1] => Array([url] => 'preview_url', [type] => 'preview') etc.` Is there a way to remain the original array structure?

Comment: Not unless you revert back to your original query. With joins the problem would be which should be the 1st one of the 4.